# vmware player - ubuntu can resolve hostname but ping fails

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Using VMware players on Windows 7 with a Ubuntu 10.04 guest.  When I ping it resolves the ip address but the ping fails.  Hopefully this is a local issue as I don't have access to any of the network equipment (routers, etc).

vmware tools is installed.

Is there any other information I can provide to help resolve this?

with NAT:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:83:4f:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.163.129  Bcast:192.168.163.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:4fc0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:50006 (50.0 KB)  TX bytes:16701 (16.7 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)
```

with Bridged:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:83:4f:c0  
          inet addr:1xx.xx3.82.49  Bcast:1xx.xx3.82.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe83:4fc0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:284 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:40350 (40.3 KB)  TX bytes:8469 (8.4 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 B)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 B)
```

Comment: Change the config of the VM network card so that it is bridged.

Comment: Same result.  I posted the ifconfig output.